# Mixed load cassandra-stress test

Tags: cassandra, stress-testing, thrift-protocol, cassandra-stress, nosql

Need some help regarding cassandra stress testing. I have installed the cassandra-stress 2.1 tool from datastax website. I want to do Read+Write stress testing in the ratio of 10:1 and using 15 threads. I somehow cant get it to work. I am able to successfully to the read and write testing seperately.

**Command I am using :**
./cassandra-stress mixed  ratio(write=1,read=10) n=10000 cl=ONE -port thrift=9160 -schema keyspace="Keyspace1" -mode thrift smart -rate threads>=15 threads\<=15 -node  192.168.5.10

**Even though I specify the port as 9160 but it is using native 9042 port.**

**I am getting the following error:**

```
    ERROR 18:03:07 Error creating pool to /192.168.5.11:9042
    com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/192.168.5.11:9042] Cannot connect

    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:106) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.PooledConnection.<init>(PooledConnection.java:32) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Factory.open(Connection.java:521) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DynamicConnectionPool.<init>(DynamicConnectionPool.java:73) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.HostConnectionPool.newInstance(HostConnectionPool.java:33) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager.replacePool(SessionManager.java:239) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager.access$400(SessionManager.java:39) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager$3.call(SessionManager.java:272) [cassandra-driver-core-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager$3.call(SessionManager.java:264) [cassandra-driver-core-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_72]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_72]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_72]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_72]
    Caused by: org.jboss.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: /192.168.5.11:9042
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.processConnectTimeout(NioClientBoss.java:137) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.process(NioClientBoss.java:83) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:318) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.run(NioClientBoss.java:42) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
    ... 3 common frames omitted
    ERROR 18:03:12 Error creating pool to /192.168.5.13:9042
    com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/192.168.5.13:9042] Cannot connect
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:106) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.PooledConnection.<init>(PooledConnection.java:32) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Factory.open(Connection.java:521) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DynamicConnectionPool.<init>(DynamicConnectionPool.java:73) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.HostConnectionPool.newInstance(HostConnectionPool.java:33) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager.replacePool(SessionManager.java:239) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager.access$400(SessionManager.java:39) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager$3.call(SessionManager.java:272) [cassandra-driver-core-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager$3.call(SessionManager.java:264) [cassandra-driver-core-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_72]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_72]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_72]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_72]
    Caused by: org.jboss.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: /192.168.5.13:9042
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.processConnectTimeout(NioClientBoss.java:137) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.process(NioClientBoss.java:83) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:318) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
    at
    org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.run(NioClientBoss.java:42) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
    ... 3 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the shell [metacharacters](http://faculty.salina.k-state.edu/tim/unix_sg/shell/metachar.html) (parantheses and angle brackets in this case).  Try this:

```
./cassandra-stress mixed ratio\(write=1,read=10\) n=10000 cl=ONE -port thrift=9160 -schema keyspace="Keyspace1" -mode thrift smart -rate threads\>=15 threads\<=15 -node 192.168.5.10
```

Comment: Thanks I did that but it did not work even then. For some reason it was connecting to 9042 regardless of the port I mentioned. Luckily I waitied longer and after it failed on 9042 for all hosts it connected on 9062 :)